# Adventure In Prolog: Why does ?- gizmo(X,X). fail?

Tags: prolog

I'm new to Prolog and working through the exercises for [Chapter 3 of Adventure In Prolog](http://www.amzi.com/AdventureInProlog/a3simple.php). Given the logicbase:

```
gizmo(a,1).
gizmo(b,3).
gizmo(a,2).
gizmo(d,5).
gizmo(c,3).
gizmo(a,3).
gizmo(c,4).
```

Why is it that

```
| ?- gizmo(X,X).
```

results in the following trace?

More specifically, why does it fail?

```
| ?- gizmo(X,X).
      1    1  Call: gizmo(_279,_279) ? c
      1    1  Fail: gizmo(_279,_279) ? c

(1 ms) no
{trace}
```

Since

```
gizmo(a,X)
```

and

```
gizmo (X,3)
```

,for example, both seem to act like wildcards and return every possible a and every possible 3 result respectively...

I thought that

```
gizmo(X,X)
```

would return every possible result for both sides (both the letters and numbers) but instead returns a fail, and no other result.

Would someone be willing to explain why it's a fail instead of returning all values from each side, keeping in mind I am a beginner?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`X` is a variable but it's a unique one. `gizmo(X,X).` will return every possible value of `X` for which it is true. But that's the same value on the left and right side because it's the same variable (namely, `X`).

If you had a fact `gizmo(z,z).`, then `gizmo(X,X).` would correctly return `X = z`.

To get every possible pairs for which `gizmo` is true, you want to use `gizmo(X,Y).` or any other variables names as long as they are different.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. 

I think I get it now. It is because of single-assignent of variables in Prolog, isn't that right?

Therefore, by asking for `gizmo(X,X).`, I’m saying give me anything that is identical on both sides. So, `gizmo(3,3).` in the logicbase would also correctly return `X = 3` and indeed any form that had the same element twice would work the same way.

I just added `gizmo(3,3).` to my logicbase and tried `gizmo(X,X).` again and it behaved just as you outlined. 

I see why it’s not like a wildcard now.

Thanks again.